# Url.Action() and nested route values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two classes:

```
    public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
    public Class2 Class2 { get; set; }
}
public class Class2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Class1Id { get; set; }
    public string Param3 { get; set; }
    public string Param4 { get; set; }
    public Class1 Class1 { get; set; }
}
```

So, I need to pass props by Url.Action method like this:

```
Url.Action("Page",new {Class2.Param1 = "some text" })
```

How can I do what I want?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you want. If you want to pass properties from class to Action you can do this:

```
public class Class1 {
    public string Ok { get; set; }
}

public class Class2 {
    private Class1 cls;

    public int Test { get; set; }

    public string Ok {
        get { return cls.Ok; }
        set { cls.Ok = value; }
    }

    public Class2(Class1 cls) {
        this.cls = cls;
    }
}

var cls = new Class2(new Class1 {
    Ok = "Text"
});
cls.Test = 3;
var s = Url.Action("Page", "Controller", cls); // Result: /Controller/Page?Test=3&Ok=Text
```

Comment: I want pass a nested object

Comment: @Drake You can pass your property to Action too `Url.Action("Page", "Controller", outerClass.NeestedObject)`.